# Did I successfully map every proof tree to a formula?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am trying to map proof trees of sequents to formulas.

Let us say that we have a semantic inference rule

$$
\frac{X \models \alpha}{Y \models \beta},
$$

which can be defined as

$$\forall\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{M} \models X \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \alpha) \Rightarrow \forall\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{M} \models Y \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \beta).$$

It turns out that for all semantic rules of a complete logical calculus of FOL, it also holds that

$$
\forall\mathcal{M}((\mathcal{M} \models X \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \alpha) \Rightarrow (\mathcal{M} \models Y \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \beta)), \qquad (*)
$$

or

$$\forall\mathcal{M}((\mathcal{M} \models X \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \alpha) \; \& \; (\mathcal{M} \models Y \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \beta) \Rightarrow (\mathcal{M} \models Z \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \gamma)), \qquad (**)$$

depending on whether a rule admits one premise or two premises.

(Note that, in this instance, $\forall$, $\&$ and $\Rightarrow$ are metalogical symbols. If you are interested in the exact inference rules I'm working with, check out p. 92 of Wolfgang Rautenberg's *A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (Third Edition). Also note that I obtained these semantic rules by replacing the $\vdash$ symbol with $\models$.)

This fact helped me map proof trees of sequents to formulas. Using soundness and completeness, we can see that a syntactic proof tree exists iff a semantic one exists. We can conceive of semantic proof trees as conjunctions of formulas (by the definition of semantic inference rules, as written above). But $(*)$ and $(**)$ also allow us merge the conjuncts into a (metalogical) formula with only one quantifier at the beginning (taking into account that $\forall \mathcal{M} \mathfrak{A} \; \& \; \forall \mathcal{M} \mathfrak{B} \Leftrightarrow \forall \mathcal{M}(\mathfrak{A} \; \& \; \mathfrak{B})$) and simplifying it into a statement about the satisfiability of a first-order formula (because $\mathcal{M} \models X \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \alpha$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{M} \models \bigwedge X \to \alpha$ and $\mathcal{M} \models \alpha \; \& \; \mathcal{M} \models \beta$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{M} \models \alpha \land \beta$). More precisely, we obtain a statement about a formula being valid, i.e. $\models \varphi$. This should establish an injective map from the set of all proof trees of a given first-order language to the set of all formulas of a given first-order language.

Did I successfully map every finite proof tree to a formula? And if so, does this have any useful consequences? Thank you for your insights! :)

P.S. I would like to thank Mauro Allegranza, who pointed out that my proof only works for finite sets $X$, $Y$, $Z$.

Comment: Not very clear... but yes, if $X$ is *finite* we have simply that $X \vDash \varphi$ is equiv to $\vDash (\bigwedge X \to \varphi)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ah yes, I forgot about this detail, thank you.

Comment: If my reading is correct, your "semantical rule" above boils down to: "from a tautology whatever, derive a tautology whatever". This seems to me to what has been done in some proof system (Enderton's) where all propositional tautologies are assumed as logical axioms at the outset. But this will work for the propositional part only (we have truth table) and not for the quantificational part, which is not decidable.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA In this question, a semantic rule for me is merely a metalogical formula of the form $\forall\mathcal{M}((\mathcal{M} \models X \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \alpha) \Rightarrow (\mathcal{M} \models Y \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \beta))$ or  $\forall\mathcal{M}((\mathcal{M} \models X \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \alpha) \; \& \; (\mathcal{M} \models Y \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \beta) \Rightarrow (\mathcal{M} \models Z \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \gamma))$, depending on whether a given semantic rule has one premise or two premises.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA A slight correction. The original definitions of semantic inference rules are of the form $\forall\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{M} \models X \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \alpha) \Rightarrow \forall\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{M} \models Y \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \beta)$ (and a similar one for rules with two premises), but there is a bijective correspondence between these formulas and the formulas I wrote in the comment above, so the original rules can be replaced with rules of the form $(*)$ and $(**)$ to get the proof started.